# Ignoring Codeigniter's _remap for certain URLs?

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I use Codeigniter's _remap function to remap all urls to www.website.com.  This works for 99% of cases, but I'd like it to ignore certain URLS (specifically /admin,/contact,/submit,/top,/browse).  These URLs have content I'd like to display.

How would I achieve this?

```
public function _remap($urlname)
{
    if($urlname == "index") {
        // If this is the index, redirect to the most recent startup
        redirect("s/".$this->Startup_model->getMostRecent(), 'refresh');
    } else {
        // If they didn't go to the index, find the startup they were after
        $id = $this->Startup_model->matchName($urlname);

        // Check to see if the name they entered was a real startup, if not redirect to missing page
        if($id == null) {
            $data['urlname'] = $urlname;
            $this->load->view('header/header');
            $this->load->view('content/missing', $data);
            $this->load->view('footer/footer');
        } else {
            // They got the name right!  Load the page...
            $data['values'] = $this->Startup_model->buildStartup($id);

            // If there was no next startup avaiable, pass that info through
            $next = $this->Startup_model->findNext($id);
            if($next == null) {
                $next = '343z61v';
            }

            // If there was no previous startup avaiable, pass that info through
            $previous = $this->Startup_model->findPrevious($id);
            if($previous == null) {
                $previous = '343z61v';
            }

            $data['next'] = $next;  
            $data['previous'] = $previous;

            $this->load->view('header/header');
            $this->load->view('content/startup', $data);
            $this->load->view('footer/footer');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could put your _remap function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function _remap($urlname, $params = array())
{
    if(is_callable(array($this, $urlname))){ //If the function exists, is called, if not using the usual
        return call_user_func_array(array(&$this, $urlname), $params);
    }elseif($urlname == "index") {
            // If this is the index, redirect to the most recent startup
            redirect("s/".$this->Startup_model->getMostRecent(), 'refresh');
    } else {
        // If they didn't go to the index, find the startup they were after
        $id = $this->Startup_model->matchName($urlname);

        // Check to see if the name they entered was a real startup, if not redirect to missing page
        if($id == null) {
            $data['urlname'] = $urlname;
            $this->load->view('header/header');
            $this->load->view('content/missing', $data);
            $this->load->view('footer/footer');
        } else {
            // They got the name right!  Load the page...
            $data['values'] = $this->Startup_model->buildStartup($id);

            // If there was no next startup avaiable, pass that info through
            $next = $this->Startup_model->findNext($id);
            if($next == null) {
                $next = '343z61v';
            }

            // If there was no previous startup avaiable, pass that info through
            $previous = $this->Startup_model->findPrevious($id);
            if($previous == null) {
                $previous = '343z61v';
            }

            $data['next'] = $next;  
            $data['previous'] = $previous;

            $this->load->view('header/header');
            $this->load->view('content/startup', $data);
            $this->load->view('footer/footer');
        }
    }
}
```

Note:
Function index() should not exist

Answer (score 1):

So you're asking how to selectively not remap certain urls?  If so, add this to your if statement before the else:

```
else if (in_array($urlname, array('admin', 'contact', 'etc')))
{
    $this->$urlname;
}
```